# In MongoDB v6 or higher, can you do an aggregate query over multiple views?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, query-optimization

If I have to do an aggregate query which can have the 1st $match stage like this:

```
$match:{
$OR:[query1, query2, query3...]
}
```

Would it be better (in terms of performance) to write seperate views for query1,2,3 ... and then write an aggregate query to combine them?

Is this possible to do in an aggregate query?

Answer (score 0):

Neither, nor; you cannot base an aggregation on multiple views and I don't think that it would be an improvement in terms of performance.

With the current form, you query the collection once, ideally an index supports the query. If you'd base the aggregation on multiple views, you'd have to query the collection several times.

It would be technically possible that you query the collection in an aggregation and add `$lookup` stages for the other `$or` conditions, but as `$lookup` is one of the more expensive stages this would neither lead to better performance nor would it be easier to comprehend if you or someone else looks at the aggregation pipeline after some time.

What you could do, however, is to pre-compute the result of the `$or` and store it in a property on the documents if the conditions are only based on the content of the documents (and not on the current time for instance). You could create a [partial index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/) that contains only the documents that fulfill the condition to support the aggregation and reduce index size.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand it would be costly to join views in an aggregate queey, just wanted to ask if it was possible. 
Currently the inner queries are such that they might need more than 1 indexes so partial index would not really help. I am not sure if MongoDB query optimizer would internall break the $match into multiple matches, since 1 index might not be enough.